Should We Completely remove this Question?
I edited this question (that link goes to the revision history) in order to make it more targeted, and without following the link. I was looking through the revision history afterwards and noticed that the question was actually much more straightforward at first, before the link to an external forum was added.
Did anyone actually click on that link to the external forum and see what the user was banned for on that forum? I only bring this up because it's pretty bad, and I'm not sure we should even have a link to the archived version of his post on this site. The topic is both NSFW and illegal, for the record. Currently the question is just closed for being off-topic, but it may need to be removed. I think a moderator should review it more closely.

Up-voted +1. Fully agree.

Yeah, as an exception (which is what moderators are - glorified exception handlers), I think it's more appropriate to just delete it, which is what I did.
